# How to change the SharePoint 2013 logo image dynamically?

Tags: 2013, javascript, css, site-logo

Is there any way to change the SharePoint 2013 logo dynamically, ideally via javascript?

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("onetidHeadbnnr0").src="\path\image.png";
```

Also tried:

```
 div = document.getElementById('onetidHeadbnnr2');
            div.setAttribute("LogoImageUrl", "\path\image.png;");
```

Both above are not working. I tried using an alert box to debug. There is some issue at the div.setAttribute for this control.

Comment: How are you executing it? Are you waiting for the DOM to be completed?

Comment: Robert, I have a scirpt tag right before the closing head tag. How can I check if page is loaded using the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames?

Comment: Are you writing this is inside document.ready?

Comment: No I am using simple javascript. I am new to this. I am using <script> tags before closing head tag.

Comment: Is this on premises or O365? If it's O365 just note that Microsoft has a track record of changing things like element IDs without notice, so what works today may not necessarily work tomorrow. A safer bet, since that's the only image in that area would be to scope a search to the class and then look for an `img` tag, as opposed to a specific ID.

Answer (score 1):

which sharepoint logo were you trying to replace? Try the code below. It will replace the logo in the suitebar after the page has finished loading.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    //change suitebar logo hack
    var suitebar = $("#suiteBar");
    var branding = suitebar.find(".ms-core-brandingText");
    branding.html("<a href='/' title='Suitebar Logo'><img src='/_catalogs/masterpage/pathtoimage.png' height='30px'></a>");
});
```

Comment: the top left logo

Comment: not the sharepoint text, the image (which you can otherwise chagne from look and feel

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late on this, but it looks like you're using the wrong element ID. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2").src="http://path/to/image.png";
```